# Javascript attr change with fade issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, src, attr

I'm trying to have a small gallery. 1 large image with 3 underneath.
When one of the images underneath is clicked, it will change the img src of the main/large image with a fade animation.

the html is -

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
                <img alt="Bentley Flying Spur" id="main1" src="img/gallery/flying-spur/1.JPG" style="border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;" width="100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
                <a class="altimage1" href="" title="switch"><img alt="" src="img/gallery/flying-spur/1.JPG" width="100%" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
                <a class="altimage2" href="" title="switch"><img alt="" src="img/gallery/flying-spur/2.JPG" width="100%" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
                <a class="altimage3" href="" title="switch"><img alt="" src="img/gallery/flying-spur/3.JPG" width="100%" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>
            Flying Spur W12
        </h2>
        <p>
            Colour | <strong>Sapphire Blue</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            Engine | <strong>6.0 litre twin-turbocharged W12</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            Max Power | <strong>616 bhp / 460kW / 625 PS @ 6,000RPM</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            Top Speed | <strong>199mph / 320km/h</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
```

and the javascript that works without the fade is....

```
    $(function () {
    $('.altimage1').click(function () {
        $("#main1").attr('src', "img/gallery/flying-spur/1.JPG");
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the javascript I tried for the fade is

```
$('.altimage12').click(function () {
    $("#main4").fadeOut(400);
    $("#main4").attr('src', "img/gallery/1951/3.JPG");
    $("#main4").fadeIn(400);
    return false;
});
```

But this just refreshes the page. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code, and this is how it is:

```
$('[class*="altimage"]').click(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  $("#main1").fadeOut(400, function() {
    $("#main1").attr('src', elem.find("img").attr('src')).fadeIn(400);
  });
  return false;
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4t13roxm/)

Please note that the pictures are different since they are randomly generated in the demo.

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't quite figure out how yours worked exactly but I've bastardised it to this...
https://jsfiddle.net/abcp32ko/

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

without knowing what #main4 is, the way you are calling the fade functions doesn't make much sense. because they are asynchronous you are bound to get some smoothness issues...

a better way of doing that is:

```
$('.altimage12').click(function () {

    $("#main4").fadeOut(400, function() {

    // 1st fadeout complete so now change the image
    $("#main4").attr('src', "img/gallery/1951/3.JPG");

    // and now fade in again
    $("#main4").fadeIn(400);

});


    return false;
});
```

now make sure that you have preloaded the image to get an even smoother animation

e.g.

```
var images = new Array()

function preload() {
  for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image()
    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
  }
}
preload(
  "http://your.site/img/gallery/1951/1.JPG",
  "http://your.site/img/gallery/1951/2.JPG",
  "http://your.site/img/gallery/1951/3.JPG",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found `$('.altimage12')` and `$("#main4")`, but with other selectors all works well.

```
$('#main1').click(function () {
    console.log('click');
    $("#main1").fadeOut(400);
    $("#main1").attr('src', "http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-glossy-orange-orbs-icons-business/105429-3d-glossy-orange-orb-icon-business-tool-hammer4-sc44.png");
    $("#main1").fadeIn(400);
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/aw7u2sL8/2/